# What is causing this bug in HTML 5 local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

http://jsfiddle.net/y8Uju/25/

Over there is my fiddle and if you add stuff to the list sometimes and I mean sometimes when you refresh page bottom 1 item disappears....why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reuse the 'i' variable, without declaring in your bindName function. Therefor it skips every even item in the list. Just change

```
for (i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
```

into

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputNames.length; i++) {
```

PS. please post your code on StackOverflow, instead of just referring to a jsfiddle.

Comment: thank god you are right I probably could never have caught that tiny error

Comment: You have to learn how to debug a problem. Just add a lot of alerts, or console.log to you code and check where something strange happens.